# Liferay alert user when portlet not present

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

Suppose portlet X is deployed to Liferay and has a friendly URL mapped. Suppose a user enters the Liferay Portal via a the mapped URL but the portlet is not present in the portal - it's deployed but not added to the page.

My problem is that when the user uses the mapped URL nothing happens - the portal gives no visual feedback, that the **target** portlet is not present.

How can I change that? I need some kind of an alert / notice to the user...

-- edit --

I need not use a second portlet to check the presence of yet another portlet.

Kindest regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no *natual* way to make that happen. A portlet **need not** always be installed on a page. So, the behaviour is quite normal.

One rather *hacky* solution I could think of:

1. Get hold of the `ThemeDisplay` object in a JSP using `<liferay-theme:defineObjects />` which would expose the implicit object `themeDisplay` in the JSP scope.
2. Get hold of the type settings string using:

   ```
   String typeSettings = themeDisplay.getLayout().getTypeSettings();
   ```
3. Type settings will have values like the below:

   ```
   layout-template-id=foobar_2column
   sitemap-include=1
   column-1=foo_WAR_barportlet,abc_WAR_barportlet,56_INSTANCE_K4Vv,
   column-2=baz_WAR_xyzportlet,
   sitemap-changefreq=daily
   ```
4. So if you have a non-instanceable portlet with ID `foo` inside WAR
   file `bar`, the portlet's unique ID on the layout will be
   `foo_WAR_barportlet`.
5. Once you know the portlet ID that you're expecting to be present,
   it's just a matter of string contains check.

   ```
   <% if(!typeSettings.contains("foo_WAR_barportlet")) { %>
       <h3 style="color: red">Alert! Portlet foo_WAR_barportlet not installed.</h3>
   <% } %>
   ```

You can do the above steps even inside a theme, but you'll have to do it in Velocity instead of Java then. Hope that helps.

***EDIT***

You can add this line inside your `portal_normal.vm`

```
#if(!$layout.getTypeSettings().contains("foo_WAR_barportlet"))
    <h3 style="color: red">Alert! Portlet foo_WAR_barportlet not installed.</h3>
#end
```

Comment: You can add this into the theme, but then you'll have to modify it slightly as themes are written in Velocity.

Comment: One more thing: can I gain access to typical JSP variables inside this velocity template? I'd like to get the request URL..

Comment: I think `$themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()` will give you that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve that using Inter-portlet communication, for notifying the user whether the portlet is added to the page or not. you need to create another portlet(lets call it ListenerPortlet) which by default sits on the page.

you can add the Listener portlet to the theme, so that it is by default added to every page.

Now, when you add your portlet to your page, your portlet should trigger a client-side javascript event and notify your Listener portlet that your portlet is added to your page.

From your portlet call,

```
Liferay.trigger(eventName, data)
```

and bind your Listener portlet to the event

```
 Liferay.bind(eventName, function, [scope]) //make the scope as page
```

This way your Listener portlet will know if your portlet is added to the page or not. and you can display a message to the user if the portlet is not added.

For further reference check the [IPC](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Inter-portlet+communication)

and more specifically [client-side Inter portlet communicaton](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Client-side+Inter-Portlet+Communication)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The thing is that I don't want another portlet - it can be switched off just as easy as the first portlet. I need an universal alert displayed rather by Liferay Portal than a separate portlet.

Comment: There is no such direct method provided by liferay which will tell whether a portlet is added to a page or not.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if we try this,

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout(themeDisplay.getLayout().getPlid());
LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = (LayoutTypePortlet)layout.getLayoutType();

List allPortletIds = layoutTypePortlet.getPortletIds();
```

If the list is empty then the page doesnt contain any portlets.

Gettings the `LayoutTypePortlet` ensures that page the user has been redirected to is layout type portlet.

Comment: @sharanbm, thats a good idea, but still this code will go into a portlet, which needs to be added to a page.

Comment: @Queequeg you need to create an MVCPortlet and put this code inside that, and that portlet should be added to the page.